# Making a feathered visibility map out of a binary visibility map

Tags: c, algorithm

As the topic suggests, I'm trying to calculate a ramped visibility map out of a binary map.

That is to say, I have a raster map in which each value indicates its visibility with a "1" and its invisibility with a "0".

I would like to have the boundary of the visible part in the map ramped with a cubic ramping function so that it smoothly changes from zero to one at the boundaries. I dont know how to globally calculate this smooth ramping. I need to do it in C, with an array.

Comment: Sounds great. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Why is the question tagged `c++` if you need to do it in C?

Comment: Best of luck, and thanks for the progress report!

Comment: Well of course I will report progress. Dont understand the downvotes though... Any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic algorithm is fairly simple: scan over the map looking at an NxM subset at a time (typically both N and M will equal around 5 or so). For each such window, you'll calculate one pixel of output as an average of the center pixel and its neighboring pixels. Since you want a cubic (rather than linear) transition, you'll weight each pixel based on the inverse of the cube of its distance from the center.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds very good!